# How to display child categories of all parent category within a singe loop?

Tags: categories

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'listing',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'parent' => 0,
);

$listCatTerms = get_terms( 'listing-category',$args);
    if ( ! empty( $listCatTerms ) && ! is_wp_error( $listCatTerms ) ){
        foreach ( $listCatTerms as $term ) {
            echo '<li class="lp-wrap-cats" data-catid="'.$term->term_id.'">'.$catIcon.'<span class="lp-s-cat">'.$term->name.'</span></li>';
            $defaultCats .='<li class="lp-wrap-cats" data-catid="'.$term->term_id.'">'.$catIcon.'<span class="lp-s-cat">'.$term->name.'</span></li>';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'listing',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'parent' => 0,
    );

    $listCatTerms = get_terms( 'listing-category',$args);
    if ( ! empty( $listCatTerms ) && ! is_wp_error( $listCatTerms ) ){ 
        echo "<ul>";   
        foreach ( $listCatTerms as $term ) {
            echo '<li>'.$term->name.'</li>';
            $child_terms = get_categories( array(
                'parent' => $term->term_id,
                'hide_empty' => 0 ));
            //var_dump($child_terms);
            echo "<ul>";
            foreach($child_terms as $child_term){
                echo '<li> -- '.$child_term->name.'</li>';
            }
            echo "</ul><br>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";   
    }
```

This should display the name of parent category and all its child category after.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try This Code

```
$getterms=get_terms( 'products-category', array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0 ));
foreach( $getterms as $parent_term ) 
{
  echo $parent_term->name;
  $getpchild=get_terms( 'products-category', array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => $parent_term->term_id ) );
  foreach( $getpchild as $child_term ) 
  {
    echo $child_term->name;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'listing',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'parent' => 0,
    );

    $listCatTerms = get_terms( 'listing-category',$args);

    if ( ! empty( $listCatTerms ) && ! is_wp_error( $listCatTerms ) ){ 
        echo "<ul>";   
            foreach($listCatTerms as $listCatTerm) {

                //parent categories
                echo '<li>'.$listCatTerm->name.'</li>';

                //get childern term ID  
                $term_children = get_term_children( $listCatTerm->term_id, 'listing-category' );
                foreach (  $term_children as $child  ) {                                                
                    //Get all Term data from database by Term field and data.
                    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, 'listing-category' );
                    //childern categories of its parent category
                    echo '<li class="lp-wrap-cats">'.$term->name.'</li>';
                }
            }
        echo "</ul>"; 
    }
```